# Split, extrude and mirror for low poly legs

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I am trying to create low-poly style legs. I have enabled auto-mirror for the lower body and scaled the lower face to create the boundary of the part. Now i am not sure how to create the void/gap while still preserving auto-mirror editability. is there a different strategy altogether that would be a better choice?

Thank you for your thoughts.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the modifier stack for your object and turn off the "clipping" checkbox before you execute your move/extrude. Then turn it back on as you need it.

[image: Geometry split in the way the OP was asking, with the clipping option turned off]